# which is best way including header files in .cpp or .h?

Tags: c++

```
myMath.h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
  add... something
  add... something


or

myMath.cpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
  add... something
  add... something
```

which is the best way include header files?

I knew it is better as much as .h has minimum include because #include is just copy and past

Comment: it depends on whether or not the including file really need the header to compile.

Comment: Include only what is needed for each file **individually**. Minimize includes in headers. This has most definitely been asked before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guiding principle is that every .h file must be self sufficient -- it should be compilable without any more lines of code.

The best way to test whether myMath.h is self-sufficient is make it the first file to be `#include`d in myMath.cpp. If there are any compiler errors, it means that myMath.h is not self sufficient.

myMath.cpp:

```
#include "myMath.h"

// Rest of the file.
```

The other guiding principle is that a .h file must not `#include` any other header files unless it needs something from them. You can remove `#include` lines from the header file as long as removing them does not break the self-sufficiency guideline.

Answer (score 1):

Since the header file may be included by a number of source (.cpp) files it is usually better to limit the includes in headers to minimum. This way you avoid including "too much" in source files.

To reduce that even farther, you'd often forward declare classes you only use by reference or pointer, e.g.:

```
// file.h
class Object;                          // note: no header included, clients will need to include themselves
Object* createRawObject();

// file.cpp
#include <Object.h>                    // note: header included, Object defined
Object* createRawObject() { return new Object(42); }
```

Comment: Using a pimpl is basically sacrificing run-time in favor of compile-time. Some would find this a bit controversial.

Comment: DeiDei: forward declarations and pimpl are two different things (or rather: pimpl uses forward declarations).